Contact Manager API REST with NODEJS and fastify
I'm trying to solve a proposed project. Here's what they're asking for:

A) You must implement a REST API for contact management.
This API should allow:

Creating people
Listing people
Listing the details of a person
Updating a person
Removing a person
Each person can have multiple contacts for email, phone, and addresses.

B) It should also be possible to add a contact to a person.
C) All information must be stored persistently.

I started by creating a server.js, a database.js, and a client.http. I decided to create it using only the fastify library. However, I have an error when I make a POST request in my client.http:
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-length: 137
Date: Fri, 03 May 2024 11:56:51 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "statusCode": 415,
  "code": "FST_ERR_CTP_INVALID_MEDIA_TYPE",
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "message": "Unsupported Media Type: undefined"
}

Anyone can help me?? I'm trying to figure out the problem.
Ill show you my code
server.js:
import fastify from 'fastify';
import { Database } from './database.js';

const app = fastify();
const database = new Database();

const createContactSchema = {
    body: {
        type: 'object',
        required: ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'address'],
        properties: {
            name: { type: 'string' },
            email: { type: 'string', format: 'email' },
            phone: { type: 'string' },
            address: { type: 'string' },
        },
    },
};

app.get('/contacts', async (request, reply) => {
    const contacts = await database.select('contacts');
    reply.send(contacts);
});

app.get('/contacts/:id', async (request, reply) => {
    const { id } = request.params;
    const contact = await database.select('contacts', id);
    reply.send(contact);
});

app.post('/contacts', { schema: createContactSchema }, async (request, reply) => {
    const { name, email, phone, address } = request.body;
    const contact = await database.insert('contacts', { name, email, phone, address });
    reply.send(contact);
});

app.put('/contacts/:id', async (request, reply) => {
    const { id } = request.params;
    const { name, email, phone, address } = request.body;
    const contact = await database.update('contacts', id, { name, email, phone, address });
    reply.send(contact);
});

app.delete('/contacts/:id', async (request, reply) => {
    const { id } = request.params;
    await database.delete('contacts', id);
    reply.send({ message: 'Contact deleted' });
});

app.post('/contacts/:id/emails', async (request, reply) => {
    const { id } = request.params;
    const { type, value } = request.body;
    const contact = await database.addContact(id, 'email', { type, value });
    reply.send(contact);
});

app.post('/contacts/:id/phones', async (request, reply) => {
    const { id } = request.params;
    const { type, value } = request.body;
    const contact = await database.addContact(id, 'phone', { type, value });
    reply.send(contact);
});

app.post('/contacts/:id/addresses', async (request, reply) => {
    const { id } = request.params;
    const { type, value } = request.body;
    const contact = await database.addContact(id, 'address', { type, value });
    reply.send(contact);
});

async function start() {
    try {
        await app.listen({ port: 3000 });
    } catch (err) {
        app.log.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

start();

database.js:
import fs from 'node:fs/promises';

const databasePath = new URL('./contacts.json', import.meta.url);

export class Database {
    #database = {};

    constructor() {
        fs.readFile(databasePath, 'utf8')
            .then(data => {
                this.#database = JSON.parse(data);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                this.#persist();
            });
    }

    #persist() {
        fs.writeFile(databasePath, JSON.stringify(this.#database));
    }

    select(table, id) {
        
        if (id) {
            return this.#database[table].find(contact => contact.id === id);
        }
        return this.#database[table];

        console.log(this.#database);
    }

    insert(table, data) {
        if (!this.#database[table]) {
            this.#database[table] = [];
        }

        const id = Date.now().toString();
        const contact = { id, ...data };
        this.#database[table].push(contact);
        this.#persist();
        return contact;
    }

    update(table, id, data) {
        const contact = this.select(table, id);
        if (contact) {
            Object.assign(contact, data);
            this.#persist();
        }
        return contact;
    }

    delete(table, id) {
        const index = this.#database[table].findIndex(contact => contact.id === id);
        if (index > -1) {
            this.#database[table].splice(index, 1);
            this.#persist();
        }
    }

    addContact(personId, type, value) {
        const person = this.select('contacts', personId);
        if (person) {
            const contact = { type, value };
            person[type + 's'].push(contact);
            this.update('contacts', personId, { [type + 's']: person[type + 's'] });
            return contact;
        }
        return null;
    }
}


e o meu client.http:
GET http://localhost:3000/contacts

###

POST http://localhost:3000/contacts 

Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "Teste",
  "email": "teste@example.com",
  "phone": "123456789",
  "address": "Rua ABC, 123"
}

###


GET http://localhost:3000/contacts/:id

###

PUT http://localhost:3000/contacts/:id
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "New Teste",
  "email": "newteste@example.com",
  "phone": "0123456789",
  "address": "New Rua ABC, 123"
}

###

DELETE http://localhost:3000/contacts/:id

What I tried:
Created a server.js, database.js and client.http files to set up the Fastify server.
Implemented CRUD operations for contact management as per the project requirements.
Set up routes for creating, listing, updating, and deleting contacts.
Tested the API endpoints using client.http for manual testing.
What I expected:
I expected the POST request to successfully add a new contact to a person in the database and return a confirmation response with the updated contact details.
What actually resulted:
When I make a POST request using my client.http file, I receive an error message indicating [insert specific error message here]. I've checked my server.js and database.js files for any potential issues but haven't been able to identify the root cause of the problem.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Remember to provide any relevant code snippets, error messages, and additional context to help other developers understand your problem better.

